# Database to IntelliJ(Java) connection working after delete module.java file

Tags: java, database, oracle, intellij-idea, database-connection

**Hello,
my database connection is working perfectly on every project except for this one.
See my module-info.java file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3s0w.png).**
**I get this error message:**

```
 java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:862)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at org.example/ControllFx.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:571)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1604)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:595)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context.
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:346)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:307)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketEngine(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:273)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.TcpsNTAdapter.connect(TcpsNTAdapter.java:174)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the key store.
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:619)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:324)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: SSO not found
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:871)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyStoreInstance(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:767)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:902)
    at ojdbc10/oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.getKeyManagerArray(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:610)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:700)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:868)
    ... 21 more
```

**After deleting module-info.java the connection is successful.**
**Can someone please explain me why this happens and how to solve this? :)**